# Games set in a realistic version of a city which I know well

Tags: windows, windows-10, game

I am trying not to be overly broad here, but if anyone wants to edit to reword this question, please go ahead. I realize that this is a rather usual request, but I do want to keep it on topic and hopefully get an answer or three.

In a long career, I have worked in USA, the far East and Europe, about 15 countries total. I would like to play a Windows game which satisfies my nostalgia. I don't care what genre the game is; it can be a first person shooter, an RPG, a driving game ... in fact, any kind of game.

What I am looking for is something with a fairly realistic graphical representation of the city. It doesn't have to have the complete street plan, but the more the better. It should, at the very least, have a number of noticeable landmarks. I would settle for two or three if I could explore them in depth, more if I am just looking at them from outside (maybe a dozen or so).

What I am trying to achieve is to immerse myself in a city which I know well and "feel at home" in the game.

Cities, in order of preference:

- Singapore
- Hong Kong
- Shanghai
- Yokhama
- Tokyo
- London
- Boca Raton
- Key West
- Munich
- Oslo
- Berlin
- Vienna
- Turin
- Rome

---

[Update] must work in Windows 10

Comment: Those cities all sound like places I'd like to visit, I'm a bit jealous. Except for Key West. But aside from that I want to play a game that takes place in Oslo now.

Comment: I am freelance & have worked my way around the world. I find it so much more satisfying than two week holiday visits. just curios, why not Key West? actually, a driving came with the drive through the keys from Miami to Key West would be great. Or along [Alligator Alley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_75_in_Florida#Alligator_Alley), to the Florida West Coast (hmmm, strike that - totally boring)

Comment: Arqade (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) is amore appropriate place for this question.

Comment: @Mawg, Florida just doesn't appeal to me in any way.

Comment: Shenmue II is an open-world game set in Hong Kong, but I don't know if the world map is based on real geography.

Comment: I'd answer Pokemon Go, but it doesn't support Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's midtown madness series might qualify, in particular [Midtown Madness 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midtown_Madness_2), which features London as one of the playable cities.

It is a car racing game series that focuses on letting players drive through full cities, rather than restricting them to a pre-defined track.

I cannot tell how true the modelled parts of the cities (or rather, their downtowns) are to the originals, as I have not played all parts of the series and have not been to the places of which I have played the game.

Comment: I am upvoting you, and updating the question and tags. This "Amazon page]9https://www.amazon.com/Midtown-Madness-2-PC/dp/B00004VP44) says "It won't work in 10 due to Microsoft removing the ability for the copy protection this game uses to verify the disc is in the drive".

Comment: @Mawg: Aww. Pity, I didn't know that and I haven't tried my copies in years. Still, maybe an emulated OS or a patched version of the game might work.

Comment: Yes, there was some mention on the amazon page that a VM might work. It's worth a try; I like the sound of the London black taxi challenge